# Different RegExp in JS and PHP

Tags: javascript, regex

JS:

```
'abc/foln'.match(/[^\/]*?\/?$/); // ['foln']
```

PHP:

```
preg_match_all('/[^\/]*?\/?$/', 'abc/foln', $e); // ['foln', '']
preg_match_all('/\/[^\/]*?\/?$/', 'abc/foln', $e); // ['/foln']
preg_match_all('/\/?[^\/]*?\/?$/', 'abc/foln', $e); // ['/foln', '']
```

How can i achieve the same result in PHP as in JS?

And would be interesting to know why this difference.

Comment: For shiggles, try `preg_match_all('/[^\\/]*?\\/?$/', 'abc/foln', $e);` in case the backslash needs to be escaped to a literal

Comment: result remains the same

Comment: Change `[^\/]*` to `[^\/]+` so it doesn't match an empty string at the end.

Comment: great, works with the +, you can write an answer and maybe say why such difference

Comment: They are different because PHP and JavaScript are different languages that have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @KaniLab I'll leave it to someone else to answer because I both don't have time right now and I'm not too certain why it matches an empty string at the end. I just know it does. Please do note that `preg_match_all` will match _all_ strings that match, while your JS example only matches the first one. If you add the `g` flag to the end of it they both have the same result. (`'abc/foln'.match(/[^\/]*?\/?$/g);`.)

Comment: Ok thx, i just meant to award the answer

Comment: Why are you using `preg_match_all()` with an anchored regexp? It can only match once.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `preg_match` rather than `preg_match_all`. `preg_match_all` is analogous to using JavaScript `.match()` with a regexp with the `g` modifier, e.g.

```js
console.log('abc/foln'.match(/[^\/]*?\/?$/g));
```

The reason you get an empty match when you return all matches is because the `*` and `?` quantifiers will match empty strings, so the whole regexp matches the empty string at the end of the string.

There's generally little point to returning multiple matches when the regexp is anchored with `^` or `$`, since they can only match once (unless you're using the `m` modifier, which makes them match beginning/end of lines rather than the whole string).